# How to insert/update data in firebase using javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database where a node structure is like this.How do I insert/update data from a web page using javascript? I want to insert data individually in promo_ar,promo_en and promo_fr.

I am new in firebase and the help will be much appreciated!
[image]

Comment: [Help yourself](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do it this way

```
firebase.database().ref('Promotions/promo_en').set({
    desc_promo: value,
    name_promo: value
  });
```

Remember that using set, you update elements of a node of your database, on the other hand, when you perform this type of updates, you must send both elements to update within that node, if you omit any element, it is removed from your base, for example...

```
firebase.database().ref('Promotions/promo_en').set({
    desc_promo: value,

  });
```

In this case, only desc_promo is being updated, thus eliminating the rest of the node elements.

in the same way you can insert new nodes in an element like this

```
firebase.database().ref('Promotions/promo_es').set({
    desc_promo: value,
    name_promo: value

  });
```

in this way we add the Spanish language to the Promotions node

**AGGREGATE:**

you can have as many nodes as you want below a main node, remember that if you are going to update the final node, it does not affect the higher ones, but the higher node does affect the lower ones, for example

```
firebase.database().ref('Promotions/promo_es/exchange').set(
    { 
        desc_promo: value, 
        name_promo: value 
    }
);

Promotions
        |_>promo_es
                |_>desc_promo : value 
                |_>name_promo : value 
                |_>exchange
                        |_>desc_promo : value //<-this is updated or created
                        |_>name_promo : value //<- this is updated or created
```

now if you edit the **Promotions / promo_es** node without including its sub nodes, these will be eliminated, you can perform the tests that you deem convenient in firebase to polish the method to use in your system

Comment: thank you very much! worked like a charm! :)

Comment: one more thing! if I had another node under the given node.....for example exchange under promo_es,the will it work this way?     firebase.database().ref('Promotions/promo_es/exchange').set({
    desc_promo: value,
    name_promo: value

  });

Comment: I have added information to my answer to complement this question

Comment: sorry to disturn you again man! if i want to update only one value for example desc_promo and keep the name_promo as it is,how to do this without sending any value for name_promo?

Comment: With firebase realtime database I do not think you can do that, for that I think you should use [firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) although in this section they explain how to make an update to specific points of the data [TUTORIAL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=es-419) with de update function in real time database